Unit Test - Could not mock sendgrid Response
Please find my service class
using NotificationJob.Service.Email.SendGrid;
using NotificationJob.Service.Email.Settings;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Response = SendGrid.Response;

namespace NotificationJob.Service;

public class EmailService(
        IOptions<Settings> emailAlertSettings,
        ILogger<EmailService> logger
        )  : IEmailService
{
    private readonly Settings emailAlertSettings = emailAlertSettings.Value;
    private ILogger<EmailService> _logger { get; } = logger;
    public async Task<Response> SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body, string displayName, bool isSandbox=false)
    {
        var apiKey = emailAlertSettings.SendGridKey;
        var eNotificationSenderEmailId = emailAlertSettings.ENotificationSenderEmailId;
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

        SendGridMessage sendMail = new SendGridMessage();
        sendMail.From = new EmailAddress(eNotificationSenderEmailId);
        sendMail.Subject = subject;
        sendMail.AddTo(new EmailAddress(to, displayName));


        string result = string.Empty;
        //Enable Sandbox for testing based on config value
        if (isSandbox)
        {
            sendMail.SetSandBoxMode(true);
        }
        try
        {
            sendMail.HtmlContent = body;
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(sendMail);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Email sent {to} subject {subject} displayName {displayName} @{DateTime.UtcNow}: with status code: {response.IsSuccessStatusCode}");
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error sending email  to {to} subject {subject} displayName {displayName} @{DateTime.UtcNow}: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        } 
    }
}

Pease find the unit test
public class EmailServiceTests
{
    private Mock<IOptions<Settings>> _mockSettings;
    private Mock<ILogger<EmailService>> _mockLogger;
    private EmailService _emailService;

    public EmailServiceTests()
    {
        _mockSettings = new Mock<IOptions<Settings>>();
        _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<EmailService>>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SendEmail_Success_LogsAndReturnsResponse()
    {
        // Arrange
        var to = "recipient@example.com";
        var subject = "Test Email";
        var body = "This is a test email body.";
        var displayName = "Test User";
        var apiKey = "your_api_key"; // Replace with actual API key
        var senderEmailId = "sender@example.com";

        _mockSettings.Setup(s => s.Value.SendGridKey).Returns(apiKey);
        _mockSettings.Setup(s => s.Value.ENotificationSenderEmailId).Returns(senderEmailId);

        var mockResponse = new Mock<Response>();
        mockResponse.Setup(r => r.IsSuccessStatusCode).Returns(true);

        var mockClient = new Mock<SendGridClient>(apiKey);
        mockClient.Setup(c => c.SendEmailAsync(It.IsAny<SendGridMessage>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockResponse.Object));

        _emailService = new EmailService(_mockSettings.Object, _mockLogger.Object);

        // Act
        var response = await _emailService.SendEmail(to, subject, body, displayName);

        // Assert
        mockClient.Verify(c => c.SendEmailAsync(It.IsAny<SendGridMessage>()), Times.Once);
        _mockLogger.Verify(l => l.LogInformation(
            It.Is<string>(s => s.Contains(subject) && s.Contains(displayName))), Times.Once);
        Assert.NotNull(response);
        Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }

}

The problem is getting error in  mockResponse.Setup(r => r.IsSuccessStatusCode).Returns(true); as
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: r => r.IsSuccessStatusCode
Non-overridable members (here: Response.get_IsSuccessStatusCode) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
Tried again getting this
Message: 
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: c => c.SendEmailAsync(It.IsAny(), CancellationToken.None)
Non-overridable members (here: BaseClient.SendEmailAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
Please advise how can i setup mock Response

You have to change your code design and using dependency injection. You are not able to mock the SendGridClient, because it is created inside your method. So mocking is not possible. You should introduce an interface - ISendGridService - which has all necessary methods like SendEmailAsync etc. And then mocking this Interface, which then becomes very easy.
